# Query a database/file for lon/lat within a bounding box? Google Maps

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, google-maps

I've got a JSON file that contains 30k+ objects with lon/lat.

I'm able to get the four corners of my visible frame with :

```
   let visibleRegion = mapView.projection.visibleRegion()
   let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(region: visibleRegion)
   var aNord   =   bounds.northEast.latitude
   var aEst    =   bounds.northEast.longitude
   var aSud    =   bounds.southWest.latitude
   var aOvest  =   bounds.southWest.longitude
```

When the map becomes idle, I need to perform a search through my JSON (which is currently being stored locally and will eventually be on a database) and return back only the objects whose lon / lat values fall within these bounds so I can create markers for them. I don't want to load all 30k markers at once and this is my solution for that.

I realize the psuedo logic is :

```
   for post in JSON {

    if post.lat <= aNord && post.lat >= aSud && post.long >= aOvest && post.long <= aEst{
        //within the box
    }
}
```

Is it really reasonable for every time the user's map stops, I do a query through 30k JSON objects and pull back the ones within bounds? Is there an efficient way to accomplish this and is this the correct logic to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you divide the 30k+ data into small chunks(json files) representing a specific area. For an example, divide 30k data into 30 segments each containing average 1000 locations and every segment represents a rectangle area.

Everytime user map stops, you just need check which segments overlap with the visible region and search lat-lon for those segments only.

Initially, you can store all the segments into a cloud server/database and download them to the local filesystem as you needed them.

PS: If the user zooms out to the lowest level, all of your segments will be inside the visible region and you have to download all the segments. This will be the worst case scenario and will have the same complexity as brute-force 30k+ data, for all other-case this approach will save some time.